How to get PopScope canPop state on child widget Flutter?
I want to make a custom back button that not only respect Navigation.canPop but also PopScope.canPop. I tried this logic but doesn't work.
I tried to read the PopScope source code and it uses ModalRoute under the hood and adds _popEntries accordingly. Thus, I presume ModalRoute.of(context).canPop() should give that information, but it is not.
final isDismissable = Navigator.of(context).canPop() &&
    ModalRoute.of(context).canPop(); // this is wrong

What should I use to check if PopScope is false?

Never mind, I found the solution. I was using the wrong API. It should be popDisposition instead of canPop().
ModalRoute.of(context).popDisposition will give me the state of the pop entries. So my code is now like below.
final isDismissable = Navigator.of(context).canPop() &&
    ModalRoute.of(context).popDisposition != RoutePopDisposition.doNotPop;

As it is written in the documentation, popDisposition will returns RoutePopDisposition.doNotPop if there is pop entry found with canPop false on the current route.
